# Why is there no Matrix3x3 in the System.Numerics namespace? c#

Tags: c#, macos, matrix, vector

I am trying to make a little GUI library in c#, but after doing some research on matrix transformations I found out that I need a Matrix3x3 to store rotation, scale, and translation of a Vector2. But in the C# System.Numerics there is only a Matrix3x2 or Matrix4x4? Could I use one of those instead? If so how would I go about it? And why isnt there a Matrix3x3 in the standard library?

I am very new to Matrix and Vector programming, So sorry if this is a stupid question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either a List<List<object>> or a List<Tuple>

Comment: You may be looking for [System.Drawing2D.Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix?view=netframework-4.8) which is 3x3. - And there is also [System.Drawing.ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix?view=netframework-4.8), which is 5x5. - Or take a look at [Math.NET](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/)

Comment: @Taw I cant acces the System.Drawing2D namespace, i am using Dotnet on mac

Comment: You really need to add that to the question and to the Tags!

Comment: Sorry so late but the reason Matrix3x2 is not Matrix3x3 is because of the homogeneous coordinates and linearity which makes the 3rd column always (0 0 1) so it is not stored.  So why not Matrix4x3?  The last column comes into play when you get to 3d projections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Matrix4x4`. Start with an identity matrix and fill the top left 3×3 elements with your matrix.

For example to solve a 3×3 system of equations:

```
// Find the barycentric coordinates
//
// Solve for (wA,wB,wC):
// | px |   | ax bx cx | | wA |
// | py | = | ay by cy | | wB |
// | pz |   | az bz cz | | wC |

var m = new Matrix4x4(
    A.X, B.X, C.X, 0,
    A.Y, B.Y, C.Y, 0,
    A.Z, B.Z, C.Z, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1);

if (Matrix4x4.Invert(m, out Matrix4x4 u))
{
    var w = new Vector3(
        u.M11*P.X + u.M12*P.Y + u.M13*P.Z,
        u.M21*P.X + u.M22*P.Y + u.M23*P.Z,
        u.M31*P.X + u.M32*P.Y + u.M33*P.Z);

    // ...
}
```

As for the reasons, the intent of `System.Numerics` has to be related to computer graphics since it utilizes [Homogeneous Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) in which 3D vectors contain 4 elements. Three regular coordinates and a scalar weight factor. The math with homogeneous coordinates for computer graphics is vastly simplified. The only reason there is a `Vector3` is because a `Vector4` should be treated as a vector of 3 elements plus a scalar, and thus `Vector3` should be used in composition and decomposition of the homogeneous coordinates. It means that not all 4 elements can be treated equally, and sometimes you need to do things with the vector (first three elements) separately from the scalar value (fourth element).

Also `System.Numerics` uses single precision `float` elements, which are almost never used in scientific computing, but universally applied to computer graphics for their speed. Hopefully one day when the `CLR` supports `AVX512` there will be double precision numeric intrinsics that scientists can actually use.

Comment: If I only need the matrix for vector A and vector B, can C values be set to zeros?

Comment: Sure, but why not just use two `Vector3` objects instead?

Comment: I am translating some matlab code - where pairs of vectors are added together to matrices and subtracted etc

Comment: I don't see the benefit to using `Matrix4x4` as storage only. If anything there is overhead in getting the data in and out.

Comment: You can check out my attempt at translating at: https://github.com/Lelelo1/AHRS-CSharp